# fadeOut div when scrolling in it and fade other div in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got some sections like:

```
<section id="section1">Section 1</section>
<section id="section2">Section 2</section>
<section id="section3">Section 3</section>
```

What I try to do is, when I scroll in `section1`, it fades out and `section2` fades in. When I scroll down in `section2`, `section3` fades in and when I scroll up `section1` fades in.

I tried that with this JS:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$("#section1").scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $("#section2").fadeIn();
   } else {

   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});

var lastScrollTop = 0;
$("#section2").scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $("#section3").fadeIn();
   } else {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $("#section1").fadeIn();
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});

var lastScrollTop = 0;
$("#section3").scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){

   } else {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $("#section2").fadeIn();      
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

But it just keeps scrolling normally without any fadeIn() or fadeOut().
Any way to fix this or any better ways to do it?

Comment: Can you provide some demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/)?

Comment: You've defined and initialized the `lastScrollTop` multiple times. You should probably use different variables to keep track of the scroll top value for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://scrollrevealjs.org/ it should do what you need. If i get it right.

Answer (score 0):

There's excellent plugin called `waypoints` use it with `animate.css` and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windowBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight();
$(".fade").each(function() { 
  /* .fade{opacity:0;} in css, Check the location of each desired element */
  var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();

  /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
  if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
    if ($(this).css("opacity")==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}} else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
    if ($(this).css("opacity")==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
}
});
}).scroll(); //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
});
```

Comment: just add class fade {opacity:0;} to your css file and add class="fade" to your section like so: 
<section id="section1" class="fade">Section 1</section>
<section id="section2" class="fade">Section 2</section>
<section id="section3" class="fade">Section 3</section>

Comment: and you need jQuery to do that

Comment: Thanks alot. Will try that when I am home. But it looks quiet good to me